# Is Hermitian product symmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Following Hermitian product:
$$ \langle f,g \rangle =\frac{1}{T} \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} f^*(x) g(x) dx$$
is it commutative or not? i.e does one get:
$$ \langle f,g \rangle =  \langle g,f \rangle = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} f^*(x) g(x) dx$$
or shoud we rather get : $\langle f,g \rangle = \langle g,f \rangle^{*}$ ?

By doing: 
\begin{align}
\langle f,g \rangle^{*} &= \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} (f(x)^{*} g(x))^{*} dx \\
&=\frac{1}{T} \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} (f^(x) g(x))^{*} dx \\ 
&= \langle g,f \rangle
\end{align}

Sorry if answer is evident but I don't know if operation of conjugate can be applied from outside to inside the integral.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ defined as Hermitian operators, or as general functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hilbert space of your interest, denoted by $L^2(\mathbb{C})$, is a kind of *inner product space* of square-integrable **complex** continuous functions, which is a vector space equipped with an **inner product**.

Inner products, in general, have the following properties,

1. Positive definiteness: $\langle v,v \rangle \geq 0$ and equal if and only if $v=0$
2. **Conjugate symmetry**: $\langle v,w \rangle^* = \langle w,v \rangle$
3. Linearity: $c \, \langle v,u+w \rangle = \langle c \,v,u \rangle + \langle c \,v,w \rangle $
4. Triangle-equality: $\langle u+v,w \rangle \geq \, \langle u,w \rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$

As you can see, your question is answered directly from the definition. However, it would be $\langle v,w \rangle = \langle w,v \rangle$ if the functions were real-valued.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [complex vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Complex_coordinate_space), so generically there you have the property $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle g,f\rangle^{\ast}$.

PS. You used the wrong word, it's not commutative but *symmetric*

Comment: -@Greg Paul . thanks. Can one write with general functions : $f(x)=\int h(x) dx \Rightarrow f(x)^{*}=(\int h(x) dx)^{*} = \int h^{*}(x) dx$ ? (where $*$ corresponds to conjugate)